# Force input to always be in viewport in page with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll

My website got a form that when you type something it adds error above the form. When you do this in desktop with big screen you still can see a an input even if it was moved a bit to the bottom. However when  you are using a mobile there is a possibility that when there will be a lot of errors and input will go outside a screen.

This is the problem: https://angular-wwvhcw.stackblitz.io

I tried to bind an input event and when input event happen I will scroll document to the position where the input will be virtually in the same position.

This is my code so far (I'm using Angular):

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAnchorInput]'
})
export class AnchorInputDirective {

  input: HTMLInputElement;

  @HostListener('input') onInput() {
    const position: DOMRect = this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const pos = Math.abs(this.input.scrollTop - position.y); // can't figure equation to calculate proper scroll 
    this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, pos]);
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
    this.input = el.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

Do you have any ideas to fix this issue? Maybe somebody got other way to fix this problem (cannot remove that mechanism unfortunatelly).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for the `input` event, listen to the `keyup` event and then call `scrollIntoView()` on the target element if it's not visible in the viewport.

**HTML:**

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="value" (keyup)="handleKeyup($event)" id="dupa">
```

**Controller:**

```
handleKeyup($event) {
  if (this.isInViewport($event.target)) {
    console.log("visible")
  } else {
    console.log("not visible")
    $event.target.scrollIntoView();
  }
}

isInViewport(elem) {
  var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
      bounding.top >= 0 &&
      bounding.left >= 0 &&
      bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
};
```

I forked your StackBlitz and updated it so that it works for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1sfnjj

*Source: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/*

Comment: Thank you for reponse. Your solution indeed works however problem is that everytime user types input get moved to the top of viewport.

Comment: @karoluS I've updated my answer and the StackBlitz to only scroll to the element if it's not visible in the viewport.